# Commands still run from killed armor stand

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have the following commands run by an armor stand in a function

```
say Hello. I'm here!

kill @s

execute as @s run say Still here
```

When I run it on an armor stand I get

```
[Armor Stand] Hello. I'm here!
[Armor Stand] Still here
```

My desired result is that none of the commands after it's killed will run. For some reason, I thought this was supposed to happen, but it didn't. How can it still run a command as an entity that no longer exists? Does `kill` happen at the end of the tick and it is just "qued"?

In this case, I'd just want the first say command to run and not the second. I've tried replacing `as @s` with `if entity @s` but I still get the same results. How can I use `kill` as an endpoint?

Comment: Not sure how much this applies to armor stands, but normal entities have an about 1 second kill animation. While they are dying, they can still run commands.

Comment: @Penguin, interesting. That could easily be the case but for some reason, I had in my head that killing an armor stand worked like a break / return and had no delay.

Comment: I think that in functions the commands are run within one game tick, so all the commands would be run within the same tick. And therefor the armor stand would still be alive, I think.